# Grafana canvas plugin icon and background location for Canvas, plus can I add my own icons?

Tags: grafana

How and where do I add my own diagrams to Canvas and also my own icons?

I'd like to upload my own icons and also get them to change colour like they do here, is this possible?

Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/canvas/

I dont want to sue URL images and wants to store my images somewhat locally on the docker server that is running grafana container. Also i couldn't find any way to add new/my own movable objects that would react to metric value like those wind turbines in the demo.

Googling doesnt help, GPTs are lost and giving false info(bcs this is new plugin)

Answer (score 0):

If your grafana runs in a docker container you should import your gif, png, svg or icon to the container.

The folder for icon: /usr/share/grafana/public/app/plugins/panel/icon

There is a simple command: downloads % docker cp my-background.png grafana:/usr/share/grafana/public/img/bg/my-background.png

You can also watch the this youtube video. I hope it helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIjUOr_HYFQ